# Как получить директории файлов и имена самих файлов как отчет в Excel?

Tags: python, pyqt5, excel, файловая-система, xlsx

UPD:
Ответ в комментариях, от @gil9red

пытаюсь получить отчет в `Excel` с названием папки из каталога в которой хранятся файлы, и самих файлов, но то что пробую я, выводит только `dirs` последней папки, и последний файл из него.
Делал следующим образом:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(431, 147)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.dir_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.dir_edit.setObjectName("dir_edit")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.dir_edit)
        self.btn_dir = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_dir.setObjectName("btn_dir")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_dir)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.btn_action = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_action.setObjectName("btn_action")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.btn_action)
        self.btn_exit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_exit.setObjectName("btn_exit")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.btn_exit)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 431, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btn_dir.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Каталог"))
        self.btn_action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Начать"))
        self.btn_exit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выход"))


    import os
import sys

import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
import PyQt5
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import NumLas_ui


class NumLas(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, NumLas_ui.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NumLas, self).__init__()
        self.direc = None
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btn_dir.clicked.connect(self.dir)
        self.btn_action.clicked.connect(self.action)
        self.btn_exit.clicked.connect(self.exit)

    def dir(self):
        self.direc = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Выберите каталог")
        self.dir_edit.setText(self.direc)

    def action(self):

        WB = xlsxwriter.Workbook("Test.xlsx")

        data_sheet = WB.add_worksheet('Список объектов')
        data_sheet.set_column(0, 0, 50)
        data_sheet.set_column(1, 1, 40)
        data_sheet.write('A1', 'dir')
        data_sheet.write('B1', 'file')

        if self.direc:
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.direc):
                for dir in dirs:
                    row = 1
                    col = 0
                    data_sheet.write(row, col, dir)
                    row += 1
                for file in files:
                    if file.endswith('.txt'):
                        r = 1
                        c = 0
                        data_sheet.write(r, c + 1, file)
                        r += 1

        WB.close()
        return

    def exit(self):
        self.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = NumLas()
    ui.show()
    app.exec_()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

а каталог выглядит следующим образом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я хочу сделать так, что в отчете первой колонкой выгружались `dirs`, а второй имена фалов в них, но у меня не выходит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так выглядит результат мой, но внутри папок лежит ещё несколько файлов и нужно, чтобы выгружались все файлы

Comment: А покажите, пожалуйста, скриншот экселя с текущим результатом и как вы бы хотели видеть (а то не очень понятно как имена файла выглядели бы)

Comment: Накидал прототип, как я предполагаю, https://pastebin.com/HmDDG0ym

Comment: @gil9red, добавил результат

Comment: Смотрели мой прототип?

Comment: @gil9red,  да, спасибо, то, что нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
WB = xlsxwriter.Workbook("Test.xlsx")

data_sheet = WB.add_worksheet('Список объектов')
data_sheet.set_column(0, 0, 50)
data_sheet.set_column(1, 1, 40)
data_sheet.write('A1', 'dir')
data_sheet.write('B1', 'file')

if self.direc:
    row = 1
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.direc):
        for dir_name in dirs:
            data_sheet.write(row, 0, fr'{root}\{dir_name}')
            row += 1
     
        for file in files:
            data_sheet.write(row, 1, file)
            row += 1
WB.close()
```